# Differences between the books and TV

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

My 18yo niece and I made a contest: who can find more differences between the books and Game of Thrones TV show?

My question is not answered by [What plot differences are there between the Game of Thrones TV series and the books? [closed]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2902/what-plot-differences-are-there-between-the-game-of-thrones-tv-series-and-the-bo) - that questions was (and has been closed as being) too broad. My question is more specific and I am focusing only on specific characters and how they are presented/missing/ending. Of course in the broad view the books and TV are different, look at my examples: characters that are missing, characters faith is different and characters that affect the plot, e.g. Lady Stoneheart changes the 4th book which is considered to be the worst of them.

The question [Which GoT characters do not appear in ASoIaF?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82961/which-got-characters-do-not-appear-in-asoiaf) - I am asking also about characters that appear in ASoIaF and does not appear in GoT.

The questions [Which major magic-related Game of Thrones book characters have been missing from the HBO series from S3-S5?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105371/which-major-magic-related-game-of-thrones-book-characters-have-been-missing-from) is limited to S3-S5 while I am asking about ALL Seasons (S1-S7) and ALL the Books.

My question is: Did we miss other characters that appear in the book and not on TV or vice versa?

**Here are the differences we found (in no specific order):**

- **Ser Barristan Selmy** does not die in the book. On TV Ser Barristan Selmy dies in *S5*.
- **Tyrion's face** is horribly disfigured in the book. On TV Tyrion never loses his nose.
- **Shae** uses Tyrion in the book. On TV Shae loves Tyrion and is even jealous when he marries Sansa Stark. The end of their relationship is the same in the book and on TV.
- **Robb Stark** marries Jeyne, Jeyne lives because Robb leaves his wife behind when he goes to his uncle's wedding at the Twins, a move that saves her life. On TV Robb Stark marries Talisa, Talisa dies with him in the Red Wedding.
- **Lady Stoneheart** is a zombified Catelyn Stark who kills everyone connected/related to *The Red Wedding* in the 4th book. On TV Lady Stoneheart is nowhere to be found.
- **Donal Noye** serves the *Night's Watch* in the books. On TV Donal Noye does not exist.
- **Olly** is not in the books at all. On TV Olly is a young boy living south of the wall and his village is sacked by wildlings, he joins the Night's Watch and becomes Jon Snow's assistant.
- **Ygritte** is killed anonymously in the books and everybody stabs Jon Snow. On TV Olly kills Ygritte and stabs Jon Snow.
- **'Reek'** is Ramsay's servant in the books. On TV 'Reek' is a nickname Ramsay gives Theon.
- **The Hound** is killed(?) by one of Gregor's men in the books. On TV The Hound is nearly killed by Brienne.
- **Princess Myrcella** is wounded but doesn't die in the books. On TV Princess Myrcella is poisoned and dies.
- **Varys** stays in King's Landing in the books. On TV Varys leaves King's Landing.
- **Shireen** lives in the books. On TV Shireen Dies (burned to death in S5).
- **Jaime and Cersei** (After Joffrey dies) make mutual love in the books. On TV Jaime rapes Cersei in the hall where Joffrey's body on display.
- **Mance Rayder** escapes execution in the books, later it is revealed that the burning turns out to be a trickery. On TV Mance Rayder Dies.
- **The Sand Snakes** plans are foiled in the book. On TV The Sand Snakes take over Dorne
- **Ramsay Bolton** marries and rapes Jeyne Poole in the books. On TV Ramsay Bolton marries and rapes Sansa Stark.

My question is: Does anyone know/noticed other characters that appear in the book and not on TV or vice versa?

**My question refers only to specific characters that appear in one but not the other. I am NOT asking for adaptation comparison!**

Comment: Differences? Everything

Comment: While your edit is just, it isn't in line with the content of your questions, because now you're asking about characters that are in one but not the other yet more than half your examples are in both. As your question stands I would be tempted to close it as "unclear what you're asking"

Comment: My question is not a duplicate of the questions @TheLethalCarrot is referring. Please, read my edit, That question is too broad and I am focusing only on specific characters that exist in one and not the other (e.g. Lady Stoneheart, Olli, etc)

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/105371/58193

Comment: Dupe: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/82961/58193

Comment: Again, you may have edited to claim that's what you're asking, but your examples don't align with that, eitherway, if that is your question, it is still a dupe

Comment: Just a note though that asking about what characters appear in one and not the other is by definition an adaptation comparison.

Comment: scifi.stackexchange.com/q/82961/58193 the question is on "Which major magic-related Game of Thrones book characters have been missing from the HBO series from S3-S5?" I am asking about any character on any season, in any book. more broad than the question.

Comment: "Which GoT characters do not appear in ASoIaF?" - my questions is also vice versa: which characters on ASoIaF does not appear in GoT.

Comment: @BinyaminRegev have you even bothered reading the answers, TheLethalCarrots answer on "Which GoT characters do not appear in ASoIaF" covers all characters, not just "magic-related" ones. Also incorrect, your question is about which doesn't appear in both: *My question refers only to specific characters that appear in one but not the other. I am NOT asking about adaptation comparison!*

Comment: You can say that you don't know the answer, it's okay, to admit that even you are not perfect and don't know everything.

Comment: I don't know everything, however the answers are covered elsewhere, I'm sorry. Your question is not very clear and you've changed the meaning of it several times now in a quick attempt to keep it open. You have every right to edit your question, but I suggest you take time with the next edit and make it clear what you're asking and what examples you choose to use. You can then submit the edit and it will go through the re-open queue. If it is no longer a dupe, then it will be re-opened. If it is unclear, too broad or a dupe, it will remain closed.

Comment: No, they are not covered elsewhere. My niece just found 1 other character. We will keep looking on our own and with people who like challenges. We simply love to read and find where TV/movies take artistic freedom too far.

Comment: If you like challenges, take a look at [puzzling.se] they may have some interesting puzzles. On topic, I suggest you read through the other questions, they have some interesting details about characters that are different or in one entity but not the other which you might not have guessed yet! Don't worry about your question being a dupe, that only means it was so interesting it was asked twice! Your question will help widen the net of searches that leads users to their answers, so thank you!